# Need a creative way to post employee bios

Tags: joomla, joomla1.5, joomla-extensions

i need to find a creative way to post employee bios.

right now i just have it in a table, alternating bio and pictures, like this:

person 1
[picture] [bio]

person 2
[bio] [picture]

person 3
[picture] [bio]

person 4
[bio] [picture]

its really hard to maintain when i need to add or remove a person.

could anyone suggest an extension i could use for this?

it does not have to use a table, just look good(creative) and be easy to maintain

thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution - [DJCatalog Extension](http://extensions.joomla.org/extensions/directory-a-documentation/directory/8325) did the trick :)

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest the best way would be to create a category for your employees then use a category blog layout with multiple columns. This would give you a nice first page where you could have name+picture, and then upon clicking their name you view an individual page about that person.

- Should you choose this solution (I am assuming 1.5). Create a category for employees and create an article for each employee within this category. Seperate the photo from the main content using the "read more" button.
- Then goto menus->main menu->"new"
- The type you want to select is articles -> category -> category blog layout.
- On the next page, pick the category you created earlier on the RH side, and just below that you can specify how many columns and how many employees to view per page.

Hope this helps, the same method loosely applies to Joomla 1.6, however, categories are setup differently.